# Access to libltdl's module reference count

Tags: c, linux, libtool

I'm using libltdl in my C code to dynamically load libtool made shared object files. Apparently a reference count is internally kept for each module handle returned by libtool's version of dlopen. Is there any way to access this reference count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const lt_dlinfo *info;
info = lt_dlgetinfo(myhandle);
printf("refcount is %d\n", info->ref_count);
```